# Find the general formula for $x_k.$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that the sequence $x_0, x_1, x_2...$ is defined by $x_0 = 0, x_1 = 1, x_2 = 5,$ and $$ x_{k+3} = 8x_{k+2}−17x_{k+1}+10x_k$$ for $k≥0.$ Find a general formula for $x_k$.

Putting in the format $x_k = r^k$

I get $r^3 = 8r^2-17r+10$ after dividing both sides with $r^k$

To make a long calculation short, I've found that r = 1, 2, 5, are the solutions. (I am only confused about a small part of this question)

Since there are three terms, we then want to find A B C in which

$$0 = A + B + C\\1 = A + 2B + 5C\\
5 = ????$$

What should i fill in the last equation?

Comment: you general solution is $x_k = A + B\, 2^k + C\, 5^k$ so the last equation should be $5 = A + 4B + 25C$

Comment: forgive me, It was a typo. But how do you get A + 4B + 25C?

Comment: do you get it. i edited my pref comment.

Comment: Aaah thank you. I understand it now.

Comment: you are welcome. good luck.